# Does .css() automatically add vendor prefixes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vendor-prefix

I have some code:

```
$("#" + this.id).css("border-radius",this.radius + "px");
$("#" + this.id).css("-moz-border-radius",this.radius + "px");
$("#" + this.id).css("-webkit-border-radius",this.radius + "px");
```

I am trying to improve lines like this by using JSON to apply them (as shown in jQuery's docs) or by removing the vendor prefix versions completely.

Does jQuery's `.css()` method automatically apply any required vendor prefixes when changing CSS properties on an element?

Comment: Why don't you use style files instead of javascript, simply add class with venodrs, many extensions add  to ide such functionality. And its more readable

Comment: You should really write those lines of CSS in the reverse order, so that if both versions exist, the standards one overrides the experimental/vendor one.

Comment: specifically in terms of `border-radius`, you can probably drop the prefixes anyway; it's been standardised for long enough that there's really not many browsers out there in the wild that still need the prefix. See http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: If you don't mind using a library [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) helps.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As @zeroflagL wrote it appears that since jQuery 1.8.0 `.css()` does add browser specific prefixes ([see this](http://www.richardfawcett.net/demos/jquery_1.8.0_testing.html)).

In earlier versions this is not done automatically by jQuery's `.css()`. You will have to do it by yourself or  you can use jQuery's [`.cssHooks()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) to add vendor prefixes.

**Code example from [here](https://gist.github.com/cballou/4007063):**

```
(function($) {
  if ( !$.cssHooks ) {
    throw("jQuery 1.4.3+ is needed for this plugin to work");
    return;
  }

  function styleSupport( prop ) {
    var vendorProp, supportedProp,
        capProp = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1),
        prefixes = [ "Moz", "Webkit", "O", "ms" ],
        div = document.createElement( "div" );

    if ( prop in div.style ) {
      supportedProp = prop;
    } else {
      for ( var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ) {
        vendorProp = prefixes[i] + capProp;
        if ( vendorProp in div.style ) {
          supportedProp = vendorProp;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    div = null;
    $.support[ prop ] = supportedProp
    return supportedProp;
  }

  // check for style support of your property 
  // TODO by user: swap out myCssPropName for css property
  var myCssPropName = styleSupport("myCssPropName");

  // set cssHooks only for browsers that
  // support a vendor-prefixed border radius
  if (myCssPropName && myCssPropName !== 'myCssPropName') {
    $.cssHooks["myCssPropName"] = {
      get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
        // handle getting the CSS property
        return $.css(elem, myCssPropName);
      },
      set: function(elem, value) {
        // handle setting the CSS value
        elem.style[myCssPropName] = value;
      }
    };
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for cssHooks. Is there a repository with the common prefixes?

Comment: I've seen in the examples: `prefixes = [ "Moz", "Webkit", "O", "ms" ]`. added a code example

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove the vendor prefix versions with advice from caniuse.com

Comment: I couldn't find anything about this in the docs. do you have some reference?

Comment: @YotamOmer check these links
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.css
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=_vendorPropName
http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=_cssPrefixes

Comment: Note that jQuery does this only for the property name, not for the property value. Using `$('body').css('cursor', 'grab')` will not automatically transform to `.css('cursor', '-webkit-grab')` on Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

jQuery DOES add vendor prefixes. It first checks for the presence of the standard property and if it's not found for a vendor prefixed version. From the source:

```
// return a css property mapped to a potentially vendor prefixed property
function vendorPropName( style, name ) {
    // shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed
    if ( name in style ) {
      return name;
     }

    // check for vendor prefixed names
    ...
```

I don't know since which version, but I think 1.8.

Comment: cant find that method anymore - pity.

Answer (score 7):

This is now confirmed in the official docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/

### Setter ( `.css( propertyName, value )` )

> As of jQuery 1.8, the `.css()` setter will automatically take care of prefixing the property name. For example, take `.css( "user-select", "none" )` in Chrome/Safari will set it as `-webkit-user-select`, Firefox will use `-moz-user-select`, and IE10 will use `-ms-user-select`.

### Getter ( `.css( propertyName )`  )

> The `.css()` method is a convenient way to get a computed style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties (the `getComputedStyle()` method in standards-based browsers versus the `currentStyle` and `runtimeStyle` properties in Internet Explorer prior to version 9) and the different terms browsers use for certain properties. For example, Internet Explorer's DOM implementation refers to the float property as `styleFloat`, while W3C standards-compliant browsers refer to it as `cssFloat`. For consistency, you can simply use `"float"`, and jQuery will translate it to the correct value for each browser.

It doesn't explicitly mention vendor prefixes in the getter context but it's easy to test. For example, `$element.css('border-radius')` on Chrome returns values set as `border-radius` or `-webkit-border-radius` and ignores values set as `-moz-border-radius`.

Just keep in mind that it's inconsistent across browsers for shorthand properties:

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered `border-width`, use: `$( elem ).css( "borderTopWidth" )`, `$( elem ).css( "borderBottomWidth" )`, and so on.