# Add Jquery Attribute and CSS in the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the image on hover but it doesnt seem to work, any idea? the css doesnt also work. basically what it does is when the link is hover, the image should change with a scaling effect

```
<script>
    $('#c_menu2').hover(function(){
        $('img.hut2').attr("src", "Images/hut2.png");   
        $('img').css( { -moz-transform:'scale(1.04)', 
   -webkit-transform:'scale(1.04)',
   -o-transform:'scale(1.04)' } );
        $(this).css( { color: '#b26c64'});          
    }, function(){
         $('img.hut2').attr("src", "Images/hut.png");  
        $('img.hut2').css( { height:'195px',
    width:'240px',
    -moz-transition:'-moz-transform 0.1s ease-in',
    -webkit-transition:'-webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in',
    -o-transition:'-o-transform 0.1s ease-in' } );
        $(this).css( { color: '#000'}); 

    });

    $('img.hut2').hover(function(){
        $('#c_menu2').css( { color: '#b26c64'});


    }, function(){
        $('#c_menu2').css({ color: '#000'});            

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with the HTML, CSS and jQuery?

Comment: Is it changing color?

Comment: try to wrap the css declaration with quotes, eg. `"-webkit-transform"`

Comment: The `-webkit-/-moz-/-o-` prefixes are automatically added to `.css()` with jQuery v1.8 or above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487716/does-css-automatically-add-vendor-prefixes