# JQuery scrollTop animation choppy in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop

I have an element I'm applying some basic transitions to based on scroll position. It works smoothly as expected in Safari and Firefox, but scrolling in Chrome is very choppy.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var divUp = $('.fade');
  var divDown = $('.fade-down');
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    divUp.css({ 
        'top'     : -(st/6)+"px", 
        'opacity' : 1 - st/400
    });
    divDown.css({
        'opacity' : 1 - st/400
    }); 
  });
});
```

I commented out each `CSS` property individually, but Chrome is choppy either way. The `top` property is moving a relatively positioned element.

How can I achieve the desired effect while still making Chrome's JS engine happy? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure that `st` variable contains exactly what you want.

Comment: @GoogleHireMe it's achieving exactly what I want - simultaneously fading and element and moving its position on scroll. The issue is just some choppiness in Google Chrome.

Comment: @GoogleHireMe Has Google hired you yet?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan they work on that ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're experiencing [layout thrashing](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/).

Changing an element's `top` property invalidates the current [layout](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction). Usually this prompts the browser to re-compute the layout asynchronously (i.e. not immediately).

However, calling `scrollTop` [forces the browser to re-layout synchronously](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html). Because you call it in a scroll event handler, this happens repeatedly in a very short space of time. This sequence of DOM write-reads is a known cause of [jank](http://jankfree.org/).

To improve performance you need to prevent layout thrashing. Changing the CSS `transform` (and `opacity`) properties [does not invalidate the browser's layout](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) - they only require a [composite](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/), which is much faster.

If you animate a `transform: translateY` instead of `top` the browser won't need to compute costly calculations on every animation frame:

```
divUp.css({ 
  'transform': 'translateY( ' + (-(st/6)) + 'px)', 
  'opacity': 1 - st/400
});
```

You can help the browser optimise for the transition by setting the CSS [will-change](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/) property:

```
.your-div {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Further reading:

- [Jank free](http://jankfree.org/) - Articles on improving web app performance
- [CSS Triggers](http://csstriggers.com/) - Lists the steps that browsers need to take when each CSS property is changed

Comment: What a fantastic response, so informative - thank you! Using the `transform` property definitely improved performance, however, Safari is no longer transitioning the element. I tried using the `-webkit` vendor prefix but that did not work either. Any suggestions on what this could be? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Is it working in other browsers? According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), Safari has always supported `-webkit-transform`, though it is not yet supported without the prefix,. Also, it seems that [jQuery automatically adds prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487716/does-css-automatically-add-vendor-prefixes) so that shouldn't be a problem. Can you make a JSFiddle with a simplified version?

Comment: Ok, I created a crude fiddle to reproduce the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/7uusvfwp/

Comment: Nice! you've found a way to break webkit :) The good news is that your transition is beautifully smooth everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, and I really appreciate your help! It's for a personal website so I can live with Safari just fading it out but this is very strange.

Comment: Haha, I figured it out. It was a typo in my answer! The `translateY` rule was missing a close bracket. It should be `'translateY( ' + (-(st/6)) + 'px)'`. It looks like the other CSS engines are more tolerant that webkit.

Comment: @joews As I can see, opacity triggers Composite and Paint, Webkit and Edge trigger layout in addition.

Comment: Why not just recommend: `$('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 },"slow");` Instead of zero, you set what you need.