# How to Modify css by jquery with vendor prefix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vendor-prefix, autoprefixer

I am trying to change a jquery ui slider,s background css with vendor prefixes. I am using linear gradient. I need support for al most all browser. I have set some css with vendor prefixes in css stylesheet and I want to change gradient via javascript. I need css with this 5 prefixes

- -webkit-
- -moz-
- -o-
- -ms-
- -khtml-

  Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/x50wLd79/3/)

  ```
  $(function() {
     $( "#range-slider1" ).slider({
        range:false,
        min: 0,
        max: 360,
        value: 0,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
           var hue = ui.value,
               sat = $('#range-slider2').slider('value'),
               light = $('#range-slider3').slider('value'),
               alpha = $('#range-slider4').slider('value'),
               hsla = "hsla(" + hue + "," + sat + "%, " + light + "%, " + alpha + ")",
           satRangeW = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(" + ui.value + ", 0%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 20%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 40%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 60%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 80%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 100%, 50%, 1))",
          satRangeMo = "-moz-linear-gradient(left, hsla(" + ui.value + ", 0%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 20%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 40%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 60%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 80%, 50%, 1),hsla(" + ui.value + ", 100%, 50%, 1))";
          $("#slidevalue").text(hsla);
          $(".slidevalue").css('background-color', hsla);
          $("#range-slider2").css("background", satRangeW);

        }
     });

      $( "#range-slider2" ).slider({
         range:false,
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         value: 100,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var hue = $('#range-slider1').slider('value'),
                sat = ui.value,
                light = $('#range-slider3').slider('value'),
                alpha = $('#range-slider4').slider('value'),
                hsla = "hsla(" + hue + "," + sat + "%, " + light + "%, " + alpha + ")";
            $("#slidevalue").text(hsla);
            $(".slidevalue").css('background-color', hsla);

         }
      });
      $( "#range-slider3" ).slider({
         range:false,
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         value: 50,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var hue = $('#range-slider1').slider('value'),
                sat = $('#range-slider2').slider('value'),
                light = ui.value,
                alpha = $('#range-slider4').slider('value'),
                hsla = "hsla(" + hue + "," + sat + "%, " + light + "%, " + alpha + ")";
            $("#slidevalue").text(hsla);
            $(".slidevalue").css('background-color', hsla);

         }
      });
      $( "#range-slider4" ).slider({
         range:false,
         min: 0,
         max: 1,
         value: 1,
         step: 0.01,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var hue = $('#range-slider1').slider('value'),
                sat = $('#range-slider2').slider('value'),
                light =  $('#range-slider3').slider('value'),
                alpha = ui.value,
                hsla = "hsla(" + hue + "," + sat + "%, " + light + "%, " + alpha + ")";
            $("#slidevalue").text(hsla);
            $(".slidevalue").css('background-color', hsla);

         }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487716/does-css-automatically-add-vendor-prefixes/17487728 ( the vendor prefix is added with `.css()` )

Comment: I saw this question. Is it possible to do without any plugin?

Comment: `.css` is part of jquery, i don't understand?

Comment: Yes, `.css()` is a method that you can call on a jQuery object. The code is already using it as I pointed out

Comment: just use the suffix `linear-gradient`, jquery will handle the vendor prefixes per the SO link i posted above ;)

Comment: I tested on firefox. It does not working.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? This was added/fixed in 1.8... http://www.richardfawcett.net/demos/jquery_1.8.0_testing.html

Comment: I my real project i am using 1.11.0  but due to jsfiddle problem I am using 1.8 on jsfiddle.( It dont give jq ui option on 1.11.0 )

Answer (score 0):

You already have code showing how to modify CSS via jQuery, for example:

```
 $(".slidevalue").css('background-color', hsla);
```

You would use this same syntax, just supply the CSS property as the first parameter and the value as the second. For example:

```
 $(".slidevalue").css('-webkit-border-radius', "5px");
```

Comment: I am using linear-gradient.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just use -webkit-linear-gradient- then. Whatever CSS property you need, just supply that as a string in the first parameter.