# How to add vendor prefixes in css using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add vendor prefixes -webkit-transform, -moz-transform in css using jQuery but for some reason they are not added when the inspect elements. Am I missing anything

```
$('#show').css({
  'transform':'translateY(-60px)', 
  '-webkit-transform':'translateY(-60px)', 
  '-moz-transform':'translateY(-60px)'
});
```

But when I inspect element on browsers, I can only see
 `transform: translateY(-60px);`

Comment: jQuery is smart enough to put it. If you really need, use `prefixr.min.js`. jQuery first checks for the browser and gives it based on which particular one it needs.

Comment: So, you mean and what I heard is that I need not worry about this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487716/does-css-automatically-add-vendor-prefixes/17487728

Comment: @Ayanize Yes. See: http://www.richardfawcett.net/demos/jquery_1.8.0_testing.html.