# How to save a rotated image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var rotation = 0;
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('.rotate').click(function() {
    rotation += 90;
    $(this).rotate(rotation);
});


</script>
```

```html
 <a href="image/<?php echo $data['dir']; ?>" download="image/<?php echo $data['dir']; ?>">Download This Image</a>
```

I want to rotate an image with jQuery, then I want to be able to save the resulting image which is the rotated version of the origianl. I followed the instructions at:
[How to rotate a div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery/17348698#17348698?newreg=cc57b13e32014ca5b0e2d03d9de5ca3c) without much success. What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: You need to show the code you are actually using. We have no way of helping if we can't see how you are trying to do it. Also that link shows how to rotate an element, if you are trying to do image manipulation you have to use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: i have edited my post, sorry :)

Comment: css only rotates the image on the screen, doesn't change the orientation of the Image itself.  To Achieve this you could render the image (rotated) into a canvas and then save the imageData of the canvas.

Comment: when i follow this link : http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html the problem is done. i can rotate and save them. thanks for all response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform property modifies the coordinate space of the CSS visual formatting model and does not modify the source image. You will instead want to load the image into a canvas element and then perform your modifications using the canvas API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API