# Add, resize , position ,color change text inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm looking forward to creating a very simple way that allows users to write, resize, position or change the color of a text inside a `<div>`. I know jQuery little bit.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="canvas">
    <div id ="u-test-id" class="u-test-class"  contenteditable="true">
        Testing
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `.canvas` is a `<div>`, sometimes it contains an image or another background color. I already  write the code to change the color and background image of that  `<div class="canvas">`.
What I need is that the **user can enter the text very easily and he can style it as he wishes**. Please see the **image**:

[image]

This image i capure from mailchimp. In mailchimp when we creating an template design , it will provide the same thing i wanted . Here user can add text , he can rotate text , change font family, color etc .

Actually the color and font family things , i know how to do this with jquery .But the rotation of the text div is complicated i think. *How to do this **rotation** ?*

Here I am not asking for code, but I want to see a working demo that helps me to understand the working and learn jQuery. Please anyone can give the sample for this work, or suggest any free jQuery plugin or the basic code.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Thank you prasad for the quick response . I already aware of this function. But in my case resize() is not enough .

Comment: I think You need like a XL sheet input box

Comment: no. Please see this http://www.jqueryrain.com/?fjpPW0bb . here image , but i need text instead of image

Comment: apply the --  contenteditable="true" -- attribute to the parent DIV, Most modern browsers come with built in editor tools...

Comment: I think this is cropping tool, It is useful for image but cropping text how that is possible ?

Comment: it is like edit text option in windows paint or like in photoshop software

Comment: Will adding a rich jQuery text editor do the job for you? for example http://jqueryte.com/demos . There are many such editors.

Comment: Please read my updated question

Comment: I think easiest way is to use textarea editable, also using jqueryrotate library will do the job, take a look at my simple example at answer @Ron Then you can place over, the buttons floating to add functionalities.

Comment: Can this plnkr help: http://plnkr.co/edit/xaCWl9Havv1ow7bhMTf2?p=preview ?

Answer (score 4):

I found this from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/7fwgsk2m/). Lets take this scratch and start extending your functionality

**HTML**

```
<div class='resizable draggable'>
    <h1>Resize Me</h1>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $('.resizable').resizable({
        handles: {
            'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw',
            'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
            'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
            'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
            'n': '.ui-resizable-n',
            'e': '.ui-resizable-e',
            's': '.ui-resizable-s',
            'w': '.ui-resizable-w'
        }
    });
    $( '.draggable' ).draggable().on('click', function(){
        if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', true );
            $(this).prop('contenteditable','true');
            $(this).css('cursor', 'text');
        }
    })
    .on('blur', function(){
        $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', false);
        $(this).prop('contenteditable','false');
        $(this).css('cursor', 'move');
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.draggable {
    cursor: move;
}
.resizable {
    border: 1px dashed #000000;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-resizable-nw {
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    cursor: nw-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-ne {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: ne-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-sw {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: sw-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-se {
    bottom: -5px;
    right:-5px;
    cursor: se-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-n {
    top: -5px;
    left:50%;
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-s {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: s-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-w {
    left:-5px;
    top:calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.ui-resizable-e {
    right:-5px;
    top:calc(50% - 5px);
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question . Please go through http://mailchimp.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

what you need is **http://jqueryrotate.com/** in conjuction with other functions.

This example should be improved, but you have this functionalities:

1. **Rotate**
2. **Close**
3. **Edit**
4. **Dragg**
5. **Resize (textarea)**

Some **notes** about this example.

-**Rotate** is done by the jqueryrotate.com library. in this example I'm using taking 0,0 position to calculate angle, but should be improved to take angle towards the textarea to a better user experience.

-**Resize & edit** functions are supported by textarea editable, that will do quite well the job, as when resizing, it automatically resizes its parent wrapper, no need for extra code here.

-**Drag** is supported by jquery.ui , (perhaps it will be usefull to disable drag when doing rotation, in that case just need to add a flag) .

```js
//initial rotation, just for test
//$(".wrapper").rotate(-45);


//let's add draggable functionality
$( function() {
    $( ".wrapper" ).draggable();
  } );

 //close button action
 document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
};

//rotate button action
var rotate = $('#rotate')
var dragging = false;
rotate.mousedown(function() {
    dragging = true
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    dragging = false
})
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (dragging) {

        var mouse_x = e.pageX / 2;
        var mouse_y = e.pageY / 2;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - 10, mouse_y - 10);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
      
        $(".wrapper").rotate(degree);
      }
  })
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border: dotted 1px #ccc;
}
#close {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#rotate {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image:url(https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/512x512/plain/rotate_right.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: contain;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;

}
textarea {
  margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.sobekrepository.org/includes/jquery-rotate/2.2/jquery-rotate.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="close">x</span>
  <span id="rotate"></span>
<textarea contenteditable="true" id="editable">this is a textarea that i will rotate</textarea>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code . But text resizing not working . Also could you please show a working demo in jsfiddle withe image and editable text .

Comment: image? you requested for a text tool. I'll try to make the resize text function

Comment: on this jsfiddle I've made an resizable & editable text. https://jsfiddle.net/w5zfntz1/

Answer (score 0):

To rotate div, you can do it in mulitple ways. Ideally it should be implemented like the one which is explained in the below link which will support in all the browsers.
[How to rotate a div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery)

Hope this helps!!!