# Rotation doesn't apply to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a object contained inside its parent. When I apply a rotation, the CSS works fine, but jQuery isn't updating, allowing the children to move a bit outside its container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tem_class").draggable({
    containment: $(".container_class").parent()
  });
  jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
  }
});
```

Any ideas why jQuery isn't getting the new values and how to correct it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate a div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Actually it's not. I'm rotating the object using the same approach. The problem is with the containment. When the object is rotated 70 deg, it doesn't respect the containment.

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS works fine, but jQuery isn't updating"?