# Rotating a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to rotate a div element using Javascript & NOT using HTML 5?

If so what attributes of the element do I set/change to make it rotate? Ie, div.what?

PS: When I say rotate I mean rotate an imagae around an axis, not every x milliseconds show a different image rotation.

Comment: When you exclude HTML5 are you also excluding CSS3?

Comment: Well I am exclusing HTML5 because it wont work on all browsers, so if CSS3 works on all browsers(does it?) then I would use that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: IE is not fully compatible with CSS3 and HTML5 especially versions before IE9

Comment: HTML 5 and CSS3 don't exist in my book until every single major browser supports them.

Comment: @Mach now it does :) https://caniuse.com/html5semantic

Answer (score 18):

Old question, but the answer might help someone...

You can rotate elements using proprietary CSS markup in all major browsers (the term HTML5 isn't specifically relevant here though).

Example of how to rotate a element 45 degrees using CSS:

```
.example {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome & Safari */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9+ */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg); /* CSS3 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678, sizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE 7-8 */
}
```

Yes, the MSIE syntax is that horrible. Note the "sizingMethod='auto expand'" - that's crucial to avoid the result being cropped.

I'm fairly sure Matrix transforms (at least in some capacity) are also supported In MSIE 6, but it's more pernickety about under what circumstances it supports them (and it's increasingly hard to care 8).

Comment: @Zanthel, exactly! check out my answer. css3 to IETransform. The guy is a genius.

Comment: In the filter method where are you coming up with those values.. `M11=0.7071...`? What if I want to use 90deg instead, how do I calculate the new values?

Comment: Have a look at the URL posted by @Ashwin above, it can calculate them for you (there is also a link to a blog post about it on that page). Another option is css3pie.com

Comment: You can use [this link](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html) to calculate the IE Matrix values:

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to rotate a div not using HTML5, but using CSS3.

You can experiment with CSS rotation on [CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/) (toggle the .box_rotate rule on).

For more info, Google for: css rotate

If you want a way to have rotated text that works on all browsers (including IE6) then try [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late. For posterity's sake, I wanted to post [this](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/): This website is pretty good and it even performs the matrix transformations for its corresponding css3 counterparts

Comment: +! Thanks for posting a link to something that auto-generates the Matrix Transforms, was coming back here to do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Matrix in IE. Here is a function that solves it in a crossbrowser way.

http://kaisarcode.com/javascript-rotate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to do it instantaneously, than you can use 

`element.style.transform = "rotateZ(90deg");`

Make sure to use quotes around the CSS statement.

If you want it over the duration of, say, a second (I know you don't want this, I am just doing it anyways), you can put

`element.style.transition = "1s";
element.style.transform = "rotateZ(90deg)";`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my Java script code to rotate div element.
here I've a text box inside div element
if user enters **rotate** element will start to rotate
if user enters **stop** element will stop.

```js
function OnKeyUp() {
      
      let x = document.getElementById("cmd");
      x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();

        if (x.value.includes('ROTATE')) {
            Rotate('');
        }

        if (x.value.includes('STOP')) {
            //Rotate('stop');
            location.reload()
        }
    
    }
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function Rotate(cmd) {
        for (i = 0; i <= 1800; i++) {

            var deg = 'rotate(' + i/5+ 'deg)'
            document.querySelector('.box').style.transform = deg;
            await sleep(1);
            if (i == 1800) {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (cmd == 'stop') {
                i = 360;
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
<style>
    .box {
          rotate: 0deg;
         }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="box">
<label for="cmd">Command:</label>
  <input type="text" id="cmd" name="cmd" onkeyup="OnKeyUp()">
</div>
```