# CSS library to handle cross-browser rotation and transformation

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, rotation, transformation

Are there any libraries or plugins you would recommend (preferably for jQuery) that would handle CSS rotation and transformation in a cross browser manner?

So far I've found:

- CSS please, however as I understand these are just code snippets. And boy, they are ugly. I'd prefer to have this ugly css styles hidden somewhere within a library and not laying all over the place.
- jQuery seems to have a plugin for rotation named (surprise, surprise) jquery-rotate. However we all know, that jquery plugins vary very much in quality. Maybe someone has had experience with this one. **EDIT:** I overlooked the fact that it actually only handles image rotation.
- [Rotating a Div Element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery). However it's a little dated, and none of the answers seem to link to a library. Instead there are code snippets or information is provided how to do it all "by hand".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) sounds like exactly what you're after.

I present to you the insane cube: http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/cube3.html

Comment: IE is the problem - it's *[complicated](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html)*. Just look at the generated code to do it cross-browser manually. cssSandpaper takes care of all that.

Comment: I ended up doing it all through calls to `setTransform()`. It's cleaner anyway. The library rocks.

Comment: I tried to open the insane cube in IE10 and worked fine. But it broke when I switched to IE9, IE8 or IE7 mode. Any tips?

Comment: @Anar: Try testing with those actual browsers. It works for me with genuine IE9 and genuine IE8.