# Rotate div with top-left corner in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help, to rotate div to 90 degrees, based on a specific point, ie, top-left corner of that div in Internet Explorer 7 using javascript or jQuery or css or html.

I had tried with fiter,

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.00000000, M12=-1.00000000, M21=1.00000000, M22=0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

This rotates the div to 90 degrees but the top-left corner is displaced.

Comment: Refer to this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: @zdrsh that's not what he was asking for...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to let the CSS do the rotate, and then use jQuery to reposition the element to a specified set of coordinates. AFAIK, you can't provide a `filter` and restrict its rotation about a fixed point

jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It might be ok for repositioning the coordinates for 90 degree, but I need different angles, like 50 degrees and so on. So it would be helpful if could rotate the div based on top-left point.

Comment: you misunderstand my answer... I am saying that you can do the rotation with the `filter` css property, and then use jQuery to move/reposition it to your desired coordinates (after its been rotated)

Comment: of course, I understood that but I don't know how to find the initial and final coordinate of that div before and after rotation? I thought it would be more easier if there is a way to rotate that div with top-left as its center.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have it rotate around a corner with the transform-origin CSS3 property. Read more on it here: [W3C CSS3 2D Transforms - Transform Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin)

Answer (score 0):

Try [BasicImage rotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of matrix for a 90 degree rotation

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had tried this too but what I need is to rotate the div with it's top-left corner. By the way for achieving 90 degree rotation (filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);)