# Repeat css animation once with javascript

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Why can't I repeat a CSS animation with javascript once?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XtSa/

Comment: @TJ It works in Chrome as well I believe, however this is possible in other browsers such as firefox and opera with the -mozzila and -o prefixes respectively, if I recall correctly

Comment: @BubbaWoop I have delete my comment. You are right and this makes sense, due to Chrome also being powered by the webkit engine.

Comment: [javascript - Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example adapted from a deleted answer that suggested using classes.  That answer didn't quite get the animation right because it ran infinitely.

The idea is to add the class on `click` and remove it when the `animationend` event fires:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#button.animating {  
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;  
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
}
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className = 'animating';
});
btn.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
    this.className = '';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/9LYAT/

Comment: Yes I deleted it coz I misunderstood the Q :) I thought he wanted an infinite animation (coffee hasn't kicked in yet :P )

Comment: @stecb: I think you were on the right lines.  Using classes keeps it neater, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the button is only rotating once is because it's rotating **to** and **not by** 360°. It's an absolute value. To rotate again you would have to rotate from 360° to 720°. You may want to have a look at this post: [Rotating a Div Element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery) 
and specifically this jsfiddle in one of the answers: http://jsfiddle.net/uLrVy/

Comment: How do I then reset, so I don't have to do the animation with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6tZd3/

According to the [Safari CSS Visual Effects Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transitions/Transitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH4-SW8) you can just listen to `webkitTranstionEnd` event to be notified that the animation has finished. At that point you can reset your animation without animating with JavaScript.

Comment: Odd. It works on mine, which is Chrome 15.0.874.121 on Mac OS X. Not sure what might be going on.