# Create a menu with diagonally aligned tabs

Tags: css, menu, tabs

I have to make a menu with diagonally aligned tabs. This is what I'd like to obtain :

[image]

The thing is, I can't use CSS3 for compatibility reasons. I found a simple solution using images only (with jQuery-rotate) but it raises accessibility issues so I'd like to avoid it.

What would be the most efficient way to do this using CSS and a bit of JS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is impossible to rotate text without using CSS3. All other solutions will be image/canvas-based.

Comment: Try this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: Image based would be fine, I just want to avoid hard-coded solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a html `<map>`. It is widely supported and easy to use. See http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can used **css3**  **transform: rotate** for this navigations

as like this

**Css**

```
    .navi{
    list-style:none;
        margin-top:40px;
    }

    .navi li{
    float:left;
        margin-left:-10px;
    }

    .navi li a{
    background:#000;
        padding:0px 40px;
        line-height:40px;
        display:block;
        color:#fff;
        -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
transform: rotate(-60deg);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navi">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/fAkAe/2/

Upated Demo http://jsfiddle.net/fAkAe/3/

Give to `li margin-left:-xxxx`

Comment: I already tried something like that, despite the fact that it uses CSS3 I'm having trouble having equal-width tabs.

Comment: @morgi Now you can define your li margin-left accoding to as like this Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/fAkAe/3/