# Object position animation with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there is a way to animate a div (image of an arrow) so that it will appear in the middle of the page and then point to any object I want (rotate towards it) and move towards it. Sort of showing where something is located.

Is jQuery capable of such animation or should I look into other libraries?

Answer (score 0):

How to center: [Using jQuery to center a DIV on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen)

How to rotate: [Rotating a Div Element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Since it's just a simple shape I'd recommend raphaeljs. That'll work in most browsers (even IE 6).

Answer (score 0):

yes jquery is capable of providing such type of animations, you can make animation with `.animate()` method of jquery. http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

put the code at which the **arrow** should move (it's destination position) in that `.animate` method.
eg. use it in `.animate` method

```
$('#arrow').css({
 '-moz-transform':'rotate(80deg)',
 '-webkit-transform':'rotate(80deg)',
 '-o-transform':'rotate(80deg)',
 '-ms-transform':'rotate(80deg)'
});
```

there is examples are available for rotating,

[live rotate and other css demo brillian http://css3please.com/](http://css3please.com/)

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

Comment: But that's only for positioning, not rotating.

Comment: that is also possible using `rotate` in css, see my edited answer