# rotate a div using jquery and css2

Tags: jquery, css, rotation

i have a `div` i want to rotate it on `mouseenter` event,

I want the rotation to be animated not one move - like `:hover` - , with jQuery of course any ideas to make it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform

Comment: I found a lot of examples that could help you with jQuery rotation : [https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples)

Comment: You have plenty of examples around. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will find many examples if you hollow your search.
For example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792085/237838) I found this:

```
$(function() {
    var $elie = $(selectorForElementsToRotate);
    rotate(0);
    function rotate(degree) {

          // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
        $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
          // For Mozilla browser: e.g. Firefox
        $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

          // Animate rotation with a recursive call
        setTimeout(function() { rotate(++degree); },5);
    }
});
```

Comment: Another copy of code from another answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3792085/237838