# Make an image rotatable jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi Programmers of the world. I am building an online business card editor. So users can add images e.g. logo and move it or resize it using 
       jquery draggable() and  resizable().

[image: Card editor tool]
That is working perfectly. My client however insists that the tool should enable users rotate an image or element. using 'Rotatable()'. I understand there is nothing like rotatable in Jquery UI. But I have seen some online tools that rotate elements. I just dont know how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a pretty radical notion, but have you tried searching ["jQuery rotatable"](http://www.google.fr/search?q=jquery+rotatable) on Google?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div rotatable in every browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193536/make-div-rotatable-in-every-browser)

Comment: Thanks Nowhere man, pretty much what I was looking for. I had searched google but not with your keywords. Yours gave me results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the below code for that

```js
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

```css
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:327px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 105px;
    top: 38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="apDiv1"><img src="http://iconizer.net/files/DefaultIcon_ver_0.11/orig/arrow-up.png" class="image"/>
</div>
```